# Вопрос про сложение чисел с плавающей точкой

Tags: c++, float

Я разрабатываю высокодостоверную баллистику для одного игрового проекта. Особенность целевой баллистики заключается в том, что коллизии осуществляются попиксельно. Следовательно, позиции объектов должны изменяться шагами не более, чем в один пиксель. Причем, сдвиг осуществляется раздельно: сначала по оси `X`, потом по оси `Y`.

Для того, чтобы быстрые объекты обрабатывались правильно, перед просчетом приходится определять скорость самого быстрого объекта. Затем проверять, на сколько такой объект сдвинется за текущий кадр. Если он сдвинется больше, чем на пиксель, то запланированный шаг просчета уменьшается в нужное число раз.

Получается, что кадр просчета делится на подкадры. Интересный момент состоит в том, что во время просчета подкадров что-нибудь может рвануть, и у определенного объекта скорость станет слишком большой для правильной обработки даже в подкадре.

Поэтому в каждом подкадре снова определяется максимальная скорость в сцене. И вновь вычисляется величина временного шага.

Теоретически, если произошел пролаг, или скорость объекта очень высока, то может оказаться, что:

```
completed_dt + stepped_dt == completed_dt
```

То есть, учет прогресса расчетов таким простым способом станет невозможен.

Например:

```
const float a = 1`000`000f;
const float b = 0.001f;
const float c = a + b;
// c == a
```

Я понимаю, что этот исход крайне мало вероятен, потому что кадр должен разбиться на миллионы подкадров, однако.

Конечно, есть разные варианты борьбы:

- Исключить такой сценарий практически (но не теоретически), используя `double` (или `long double`);
- Построить свою математику, которая при необходимости будет переходить к мелким порядкам (возможно, рекурсивно);
- Ограничить максимально возможную скорость, а так же максимально возможное время кадра. Просто, но не правильно.

В общем, как такая аномалия математики чисел с плавающей точкой решается в ответственных вычислениях?

Comment: По формулам считать надо...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Часто стоит изменить подход - не ловить момент столкновения с уменьшающимся временным шагом, а делать расчёты движения **между событиями**.

Случилось столкновение - это событие, рассчитали скорости после него, нашли следующий момент столкновения, между ними всё течёт, как течёт.

Случилось вмешательство внешней силы  - это тоже событие, пересчитали движение в изменившихся условиях, пока не случится ещё что-то.